# C++ template won't accept iterators

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, quicksort

I'm re-learning C++, and have started by trying what should be a simple algorithm: QuickSort. My function has this signature:

```
template <class T>
void QSort(typename std::vector<T>::iterator begin, typename std::vector<T>::iterator end)
```

And it is called in my main function:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> unsort({56,32,11,45,67,81,12,5});
    std::vector<int>::iterator b=unsort.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator e=unsort.end();
    QSort(b, e);
    return 0;
}
```

And gives this error:

```
C:\Users\Deus\Projects\QSort\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\Deus\Projects\QSort\main.cpp|49|error: no matching function for call to 'QSort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >&)'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

It seems that the compiler is having trouble resolving what T should be. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or should I just declare the arguments as type T, and work with the resulting uncertainty?

Comment: "and work with the resulting uncertainty" - there shouldn't be any resulting uncertainty: the random-access iterator concept was designed to be sufficient to sort something, you're sorting something, so all you should need to know is that you have a random-access iterator. Doesn't matter to quicksort whether it's backed by a container or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no way to deduce `T` from your function call. Think about what happens when `std::vector<T>::iterator` is `T*`:

```
int *b = ...;
int *e = ...;
QSort(b, e);
```

In general, if you write `typename Something<TemplateParameter>::anotherThing`, then the `TemplateParemter` cannot be deduced in the call. It must be explicitly provided

```
QSort<int>(b, e);
```

I recommend to just use `T` as the parameter type. That will allow you to not only accept vector iterators, but also `T*`, or `std::deque<T>::iterator` and any other random access iterators.

Comment: Thanks, this all seems so silly now it's been explained to me. Looks like it's going to be a long road back to writing working programs...