# C++ invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, compilation, bitwise-operators

I'm facing a curious compilation error in C++11.

I have a templated class that define an enum class:

```
template <typename Type>
class stats {
public:
  // ...
  enum class stat {
    AVERAGE = (1 << 0),
    STANDARD_DERIVATION = (1 << 1),
    // ...
  };
  // ...
};
```

I currently want to use this enum in bitwise operations.

For example, here is an example of the usage of that enum:

```
 template <typename Type>
 void
 stats<Type>::build(stat stats) {
     if (stats & stat::AVERAGE)
         this->build_average();

     if (stats & stat::STANDARD_DEVIATION)
         this->build_standard_deviation();

     if (stats & stat::PERCENTILES)
         this->build_percentiles();

     if (stats & stat::LIMITS)
         this->build_limits();
 }
```

where we can call this function like this `stats.build(stat::AVERAGE | stat::LIMITS)`.

In order to use the `&` or the `|` operators on that enum without having to manually cast to int each time, I have defined operators:

```
template<typename T>
using stat_t = typename eip::stats<T>::stat;

template <typename Type>
stat_t<Type>
operator|(const stat_t<Type>& lhs, const stat_t<Type>& rhs) {
  return static_cast<stat_t<Type>>(static_cast<int>(lhs) | static_cast<int>(rhs));
}

template <typename Type>
stat_t<Type>
operator&(const stat_t<Type>& lhs, const stat_t<Type>& rhs) {
    return static_cast<stat_t<Type>>(static_cast<int>(lhs) & static_cast<int>(rhs));
}
```

However, if I try to compile I get the following error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('eip::stats<double>::stat' and 'eip::stats<double>::stat')
if (stats & stat::PERCENTILES)
    ~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Type'
operator&(const stat_t<Type>& lhs, const stat_t<Type>& rhs) {
^
```

I don't see why my overload is ignored. It seems that the compiler get the right types for both lhs and rhs (`eip::stats<double>::stat`) but it couldn't infer the template...

Moreover:

- Explicitly calling the operator works (`operator&<Type>(stats, stat::AVERAGE);`)
- I thought the problem was coming from the return type, but calling `stat a = stats & stat::AVERAGE;` doesn't work (same error as earlier).

Any idea?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596257/c-template-wont-accept-iterators

Comment: @chris It looks like a little bit different. In the compilation error message, the compiler seems to know the types that should be deduced (double): `'eip::stats<double>::stat' and 'eip::stats<double>::stat'`. However, it still fail to deduce the template.

Comment: The compiler knows you're passing arguments of `stats<double>::stat`, but that's not enough to deduce `Type`. What if you had `template<> class stats<int> {public: using stat = stats<double>::stat;};`? This could exist elsewhere and the compiler has no way of knowing yet. Then passing `stats<double>::stat` could just as validly deduce `Type` to be `int`.

Comment: Ok, so the error comes from the base class template. So maybe a way to get out of the problem would be to declare the enum outside the class?

Comment: You could, or you could follow the advice in the link and use `Type` instead of `stat_t<Type>`. You never use `Type` except as an argument to `stat_t` anyway.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your help!

Comment: @chris Except then you're writing `operator&(Type, Type)` which is far too broad?

Comment: @Barry, True, you could at least SFINAE it to enums, but there's no `is_nested_class_of` trait or anything. At least most things already error because they aren't convertible to `int`. In any case, the friend operator never crossed my mind, so I'm going to go in shame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.

1. This is a non-deducible context:

   ```
   template <typename Type>
   stat_t<Type>
   operator&(const stat_t<Type>& lhs, const stat_t<Type>& rhs) { ... }
   ```

   The idea is the same as if you had wrote:

   ```
   template <typename T>
   void foo(typename cls<T>::type ) { ... }
   ```

   The compiler can't figure out what `T` could be there unless you tell it too. So you'd have to define your `operator&` in a place where we don't actually need to do deduction: make it a friend operator in the class itself:

   ```
   friend stat operator&(const stat& lhs, const stat& rhs) { ... }
   ```
2. Once we fix that, we get to the other problem, which is that a `stat` isn't contextually convertable to `bool` so this expression:

   ```
   if (stats & stat::AVERAGE)
   ```

   won't compile. For that, you may want to have your `operator&` return an `int` or `bool`, or using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24298250/2069064)'s idea, add an `operator!` and use it twice.